# How to write regular expression for this condition

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have to validate some vehicle number which comes in this format
`XY-01-AA-1234`

1. XY is two alphabets
2. 01 is two digits number
3. AA is one or two alphabets that may or may not be present in the string
4. 1234 is a number between 1 to 9999

If AA is not present then the followed hypen should not be present in the string
I have tried with this :

> '[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[A-Z-]{0,2}[0-9]{1,4}'

```
check_vehicle_no(reg_no,'[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[A-Z-]{0,2}[0-9]{1,4}');
function check_vehicle_no(str,expp){
    return str.match(expp);
}
```

But it accept vehicle number in this format `XY-01--1234`.

ie, the accepted format for vehicle numbers are `XY-01-1234` or `XY-01-A-1234` or `XY-01-AA-1234`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using this regex:

```
/^[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}-(?:[A-Z]{1,2}-)?[0-9]{1,4}$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uP4cL7/1)

`(?:[A-Z]{1,2}-)?` pattern makes 1 or 2 uppercase letters followed by a hyphen **optional**.

To use it in your function:

```
function check_vehicle_no(str, expp) {
    return str.match(expp);
}
```

Then call it as:

```
var re = /^[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}-(?:[A-Z]{1,2}-)?[0-9]{1,4}$/;
check_vehicle_no(reg_no, re);
```

Note use of `/.../` instead of `'...'` for regex literal string.

**PS:** It might be better to call `regex.test`, if you just want to validate the input.

Answer (score 0):

As per your conditions,

```
[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}-([A-Z-]{0,2}.-)?[0-9]{1,4}
```

This could do that trick for checking vehicle numbers